# JPQL Hibernate access M:N attributes

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have the following table structure:

```
Customer(id, first_name, lastname),
Account(id, balance, interestrate)
```

Between them there is a proper JPA bidirectional m:n relation.
I have a set of customers belonging to that bank account in the account object, and a set of accounts belonging to that customer in the customer class.

What I want now, is a table representation of all accounts with their corresponding customers. If a customer belongs to more than one bank accounts, his/her name appears more than once in the table, and vice versa.

I have come up with this JPQL Query

```
 SELECT a
 FROM Accounts a join a.customers c
```

That worked. However, if I now want to filter the customers name, there is a problem

```
SELECT a
FROM Accounts a join a.customers c
WHERE c.firstname LIKE '%'||:1||'%' OR c.lastname LIKE '%'||:1||'%'
```

After applying the parameter, hibernate executes the query without complaining. It however gives the wrong values. It does not apply the filter in any way, as if there was no WHERE clause.

### What i have done so far:

- clean and build, netbeans sometimes messes up that one
- Rewrite query without :1
- and then I ran out of ideas.

Oh and beneath the JPA there is a postgresql library running.

Comment: 'as if there was no WHERE clause'. Enabling SQL output to determine exactly what SQL is generated would seem a good place to start: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-display-generated-sql-to-console-show_sql-format_sql-and-use_sql_comments/

Comment: Oh sorry, i already did exactly that. Hibernate understands exactly the query as it should.

Comment: Maybe you should post the generated SQL along with your mappings and your query code.

Comment: Alright, will edit...

Comment: "'%'||:1||'%'" is invalid JPQL. JPQL has CONCAT if you want to concatenate things

Comment: That could solve it, I'm going to try this, and report back.